# Moodle plugin development: custom navigation

Tags: php, moodle

I am developing in Moodle a plugin that is an extension of the Enrolment plugin (not a local plugin) (see [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Enrolment_plugins)).
I would like to create for that a custom menu (explained [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Navigation_API)) by developing custom functions implementing the menu. For example, as explained in the documentation, I may extend the navigation adding a node with:

`$previewnode = $PAGE->navigation->add('Node A', new moodle_url('/a/link/if/you/want/one.php'), navigation_node::TYPE_CONTAINER);
$thingnode = $previewnode->add(g'Leaf of A', new moodle_url('/a/link/if/you/want/one.php'));
$thingnode->make_active();`

I understand this snippet, which I can embed in a custom method. But when and from where exactly can this method be called in the plugin code? Candidate files may where I can define the method could probably be:

> plugin_name/settings.php

or

> plugin_name/lib.php

but it is not yet clear to me when the methods in this files are called in Moodle.

Comment: You should reference relevant code in your question, not just link it.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I just improved my question.